# What makes a question "active"?

Tags: discussion, active

What are the exact conditions of "Active" questions?

I guess:

1. OP posted a question.
2. OP edited the question.
3. OP commented on the question.
4. OP added an answer.
5. Others voted on the question.
6. Others edited the question.
7. Others answered the question.
8. Others commented on the question.

Which are correct and which are't?

Comment: Votes and comments do not affect 'active'ness, the rest do (see the linked duplicate).

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you! At first I couldn't find that.

Comment: @Glorfindel And I am surprised to know  that comments don't activate posts...

Comment: Actually, user AnneDaunted found it first, but the (auto-generated) comment was deleted by the system.